# Interpretation of convolution of impulse response of a lens

Tags: optics, waves, fourier-transform

Following "Introduction to Fourier Optics" by Goodman, in section 5.3 it is explained how to derive the impulse response of a lens. [image]

Where $(u,v)$ are the coordinates of the output plane while $(\xi, \eta)$ are the coordinates of the input plane.

I don't understand how to apply convolution to this impulse response function as it depends also on the input coordinates.
I would have expected a function like  $h(u,v)$ in order to obtain the final image like:
$$
U_f(u,v)=h(u,v)*U_i(u,v) = \int h(u-u',v-v')U_i(u',v') du'dv'
$$

How should I interpret the convolution operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impulse response is not "improperly" called impulse response, but the convolution is "improperly" called a convolution (by whoever). In general, the impulse response (the transfer function represented in the spatial domain) of a lens is not shift invariant. I.e. it does not only depend on the mutual distance of input and output as you shift away from the optical axis, but actually also from the distance from the optical axis itself. Hence, the general lens does not satisfy the assumptions of paraxial optics (which assumes that the distances of all mapped objects can be considered relatively small), but rather shows some [optical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration).

Then the mapping from input to output is **not** a convolution (which is a special, translationally invariant, form of linear transformation), but rather a general linear mapping ($h(u,v; \xi, \eta)$ is a matrix so to say, which also depends explicitly from input indices and output indices):
$$U_f(u,v)=\int h(u,v; \xi, \eta)U_i(\xi,\eta)d\xi d\eta$$

Answer (score 0):

In the book this function is maybe improperly called "impulse response" because as I said it depends on the coordinates of the input image. The real impulse response of the lens, also called Point Spread Function, is derived in subsequently and is:
$$
h(x,y) = \iint_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(\lambda z_2  x', \lambda z_2 y')\exp[-j2\pi (x x'+yy')]dx'dy'
$$